# How to plot multiple functions and group into color categories in R?

Tags: r

I have a table of initial speeds, launch angles, and results of a baseball projectile, like so:

```
  hit_speed    hit_angle           events
1     87.44        44.96           Double
2     83.53         8.57        Groundout
3     97.30         0.67           Single
4     78.11        36.01           Flyout
5     63.54       -26.46        Groundout
6     90.86        35.31           Flyout
```

For each of these I would like to calculate the baseball's trajectory like this:

```
feetPerSec <- hit_speed * 5280 / (60 * 60) # Convert mph to ft/s
radians <- hit_angle * pi / 180
x <- 0:500
y = 2.5 + x*tan(radians) - (32.174 * x^2)/(2*(feetPerSec*cos(radians))^2)
```

Once I have x and y coordinates for each baseball's trajectory I would like to plot them all on the same graph as lines with each unique "event" (single, double, groundout, ect.) as a different color.

I know how to graph a single trajectory, but I haven't been able to do it with multiple trajectories on the same graph with different colors for each result. Any ideas?

Edit: I should also specify I would like to plot lines, not points.

Answer (score 1):

```
row hit_speed    hit_angle           events
1     87.44        44.96           Double
2     83.53         8.57        Groundout
3     97.30         0.67           Single
4     78.11        36.01           Flyout
5     63.54       -26.46        Groundout
6     90.86        35.31           Flyout

mydata <- read.table(con <- file("clipboard"), header = T)

feetPerSec <- mydata$hit_speed * 5280 / (60 * 60) # Convert mph to ft/s
radians <- mydata$hit_angle * pi / 180
x <- 0:500
y = 2.5 + x*tan(radians) - (32.174 * x^2)/(2*(feetPerSec*cos(radians))^2)

mydata$colors <- NA
mydata$colors[mydata$events == "Groundout"] <- "blue"
mydata$colors[mydata$events == "Flyout"] <- "purple"
mydata$colors[mydata$events == "Single"] <- "orange"
mydata$colors[mydata$events == "Double"] <- "red"
plot(x,y,col=mydata$colors)
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I get a "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length" error.